# cannot find symbol symbol : variable StringUtils

Tags: jsp, apache-stringutils

I was trying to print the following statement in my jsp.

```
out.println("myBookIdStatus="+StringUtils.isEmpty(obj.getValue(0,"value")));
```

Even though I have imported `<%@page import="org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils"%>` , I am getting following error. Why is it happening??

```
cannot find symbol symbol : variable StringUtils location: class....
```

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you don't have the `commons-lang jar` file in your classpath, you have to add it in your application `WEB-INF/lib.`